# What's the easiest way to select Object(s) that don't have nested objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have `Item that has_many Posts`.

And I need to select Items that don't have ANY Posts.

My current solution is this:

```
Item.where("NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM posts p WHERE p.item_id = items.id)")
```

Is that the best way? Maybe should use OUTER JOIN somehow?

---

After reading your suggestions - I used following code:

```
Item.includes(:posts).where(:posts => {:item_id => nil})
```

Or with Squeel gem:

```
Item.includes{:posts}.where{posts.item_id == nil}
```

Which I like because it does not need any manual SQL.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.includes` creates a `LEFT JOIN` for you:

```
Item.includes(:posts).where('posts.item_id IS NULL')
```